# Python post requests causing 403 Error

Tags: python, http, cookies, python-requests

I'm currently facing 403 Error using requests python libraray whilst making a post requests for instagram.

I'm trying to follow a user using "https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/2663753/follow/" URL I got from network page in inspect element. 
This requires a POST request.

```
Remote Address:31.13.77.52:443
Request URL:https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/313746262/unfollow/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:15
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 24 Dec 2015 03:58:08 GMT
Expires:Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache

Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=86400
Vary:Cookie, Accept-Language
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0

Host:www.instagram.com
Origin:https://www.instagram.com
Referer:https://www.instagram.com/darealbre/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken:9776e6b7b249da6bd12397ef21a11928
X-Instagram-AJAX:1
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

I'm already passing in my cookie here's my code.

```
cookies_list = {'target_sig': '', 'ig_pr': '1', 'target': '', 'mid': 'VnttxgAEAAGrb1koHc8WHSK0qeyk', 'ds_user_id': '2352930331', 'sessionid': 'IGSC616b97e4de9eaabee722cb3b0c3758232253dcbea19983ea8ae7b52b1d2b9486%3AgBJyWG66Wqx3ZhebzN6mJ6ydhzPzlrcr%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_auth_user_id%22%3A2352930331%2C%22_token%22%3A%222352930331%3AEhfw99oCaIp8a6TiOjbbSHhzg6QwfV54%3Ab645bc518c898fc02c06911e79c531475c5c9f5b3fbbac054281ea6bfe0adb7d%22%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1450929608.312806%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%7D', 'ig_vw': '1680', 'csrftoken': '28de9e973017aae25868be36e0f2fffa', 's_network': ''}

    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36','X-CSRFToken':'9776e6b7b249da6bd12397ef21a11928','Cookie'}
    post_requests = requests.post('https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/2663753/follow/',cookies=cookies_list,headers=headers)
```

I got the cookie right after logging into instagram. However it keeps returning me 403 Error!

Using CURL, I pasted my CURL command in terminal and it followed the user!

```
"curl 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/330108492/follow/' -X POST -H 'Cookie: mid=VnnkDAAEAAGX-EXpxDkSsYIpk3n6; fbm_124024574287414=base_domain=.instagram.com; sessionid=IGSC88d8406c0f8996d4356abddcd986235bac1dc969a6604d8c9a205e39b95286d0%3AOGn68bqGJmIXQqLvq0i9eFbPmATqZkl5%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_auth_user_id%22%3A2352930331%2C%22_token%22%3A%222352930331%3A6DxouHjZAEq73UIarTseawN0uq8oKpLq%3Aba8a7b0655113764a9c768a62a9da856d7894686af3c6d50356d8819ad7caa52%22%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1450918827.64184%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%7D; ig_pr=1; ig_vw=1855; s_network=; csrftoken=9776e6b7b249da6bd12397ef21a11928; ds_user_id=2352930331; fbsr_124024574287414=Pv5CMlvyUnfLDZIM9oQibeNkRRGNlwu7JUEO9mtdyFs.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' -H 'Origin: https://www.instagram.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'X-Instagram-AJAX: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: https://www.instagram.com/struckbyfashion/' -H 'X-CSRFToken: 9776e6b7b249da6bd12397ef21a11928' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Content-Length: 0' --compressed"
```

That's my curl returned info

Comment: Your URL shows *unfollow*, not follow, but a 403 means forbidden. So perhaps you need an API key to do this.

Comment: My advice is to use the "Chrome dev tools", and right click on the "follow" request once it's made. Click "Copy as Curl request", paste it somewhere and analyze it to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Dan No, this has nothing to do with API. I queried the problem in google, most of the answer were mostly due to forbidden access. I'm passing in cookies, passing in headers correctly none of these seems to be working for me unfortunately.

Comment: @martin That did not help, as I was already doing that!

Comment: If the curl request works when you run it from terminal, but your python request doesn't, then you've done something wrong.

Comment: @MartinKonecny Never used CURL before, I just Copy pasted the headers in my terminal and it returned me "Status":"ok"

Comment: After doing curl, it does follow the user. I'm having hard time why it wouldn't work on my python code! Here is my CURL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first you shouldn't be posting your cookie, because it gives anyone here access to your instagram account. Make sure you logout ASAP to render this cookie invalid, then login again and keep that cookie private.

Second, don't both using the `cookies_list`. Just pass everything as a header here as follows:

```
headers = {
    'Cookie': '<Paste Everything in the Curl "Cookie" header here>',
    'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'X-Instagram-AJAX': 1,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36,(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/struckbyfashion/',
    'X-CSRFToken': '9776e6b7b249da6bd12397ef21a11928',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': 0
}

post_requests = requests.post('https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/2663753/follow/', headers=headers)
print(post_requests.text)  # {"status":"ok"}
print(post_requests.status_code)  # 200
```

Comment: Hey man, did ask you said I actually encountered same error. It says 403 still!

Comment: It will defn work.. If you logged out, make sure you are using the cookie from your new session. Make sure to also use the new csrf token

Comment: {"status":"fail","message":"unauthorized","redirect_url":"\/accounts\/login\/?next=\/web\/friendships\/3931765\/follow\/"}
403

Comment: I'm currently stuck in getting X-CSRFToken and cookies from one Url and passing it into another using requests!

Comment: Alright to elaborate my issue.
I have two URL - Once I login, I store my cookie for future requests.
However, I have no clue how to acess request headers data such as cookie,X-CSRFToken,X-Requested-WIth all these information. So I have multiple accounts that I want to follow and they all have different cookies/csrftoken. So I'd like to know how can I place these in my requests so they get thru!

Comment: You need to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-Header_Token. Instagram is creating a unique CSRF token for each session, and you need to send this value in both the `Cookie` and `X-Csrf-Token`. For even better usability, your script should handle auto log-in to the Instagram account, and fetch these values automatically.

Comment: I'm using requests library. I read their their entire documentation. This is a truly huge bottle neck to my app. Could you please tell me how possibly I can fetch these values. To login I'm using one of the python library called dryscrape which initiates a session than I save the cookie right after logging in. Than I switch to requests than use the cookies I got using dryscrape into my requests. As for auto logging in, I can simply just store my login in cookie into a file and reusage it. But could you please tell me how can I fetch CSFR Token/Cookies either using requests or anything, thanks!

Comment: Alright according to my understanding, each login session gives you csrf token which will be stay same for the entire session until you log out and log back in. I understand how to derive csrf token however not the cookie!

Comment: You receive the cookie when you login. This cookie also contains the CSRF token. But you also need to send the CSRF token separately as it's own header as well (separate from the `Cookie` header) using `X-Csrf-Token`. If you read about what a CSRF attack is, you will see why this is necessary.

Comment: Alright, the CSRF token I recieve after logging in is different from 'follow' post request. It does not stay same.

Comment: Doing lots of trail check, I figured CSFR actually same. I have a loop for 2 users. So I login, and pass in the SAME CSFR token, however I have a feeling the reason why I get 403 is due to the cookie I'm passing in itself!

Comment: Fixed it! Passed in cookies differently and not passed it into headers!